# Animate a layout constraint by changing its priority value

Tags: ios, nslayoutconstraint

I have a label containing quite a lot of text. There's a toggle for collapsing and expanding the height of the label (here it's named *"lire la suite"*) so it truncates the end of the text.

[image]

I have meticulously set the vertical content hugging priority and compression resistance so the intrinsic size has higher priority over the compression resistance.

The height constraint *(the optional constraint directly at the right of the label)* is set with a constant of `71`, just the height for 4 lines. It never changes.

Then this same constraint has a priority switching between `747` and `749` so the following happens:

- height constraint priority = `749`:

  > **compression resistance < constraint priority < hugging priority**
  >
  > Compression resistance collapses under the constraint priority, its height is `71` or less if its intrinsic size *(hugging priority)* is smaller.
- height constraint priority = `747`:

  > **constraint priority < compression resistance < hugging priority**
  >
  > The greater compression resistance forces the height to follow its intrinsic size.

This works perfectly. My issue is that I can't figure out how to animate this constraint, since every solution animates the `constant` property and not the `priority`.

I would like to know if there's a solution or a workaround.

Comment: Have you tested `layoutIfNeeded` to achieve desired animation..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By experimenting with it, it seems that you cannot animate constraints using priorities, and you are stuck either with activating/deactivating constraints, or changing their constants.

I've had a similar task a couple of days ago. An easy but a bit naive approach is to drop the constraint and use only intrinsic content size - you can set the `label.numberOfLines = 4` when it should be collapsed (thus the size won't expand over 4 lines), and `label.numberOfLines = 0`  when expanded. This is very easy and clean, however, I am not sure how that goes with animation.

A second approach is to use only the constraint and animate the constant. You have a height for 4 lines already, all you need is the height of the expanded label. You can use following extension on `UILabel` to calculate the height:

```
extension UILabel {
    func heightNeeded() -> CGFloat {
        self.layoutIfNeeded()
        let myText = self.text! as NSString
        let boundingRectangle = CGSize(width: self.bounds.width, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude)
        let labelSize = myText.boundingRect(with: boundingRectangle,
                                            options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin,
                                            attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font: self.font],
                                            context: nil)
        return labelSize.height
    }
}
```

Then all you need to animate is the:

```
labelHeightConstraint.constant = label.heightNeeded()
```

Don't forget on how to animate that constant using autolayout, see for example my [following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46589651/2912282) to another SO question.

Comment: I think there's no good way to animate the height. Text just jumps up and down each time a line appears/disappears. I put the whole in a UIView crossdisolve transition.

Comment: I would then put it to a wrapper view, set `wrapper.clipsToBounds = true`, and animate wrapper's height. To have the `...` to appear when it's closed, before animating expansion you change the number of lines, update layout, and then animate the wrapper's height.

Comment: So I guess the answer is: it's not possible to animate the `priority`. There's several workarounds, I tried the alternative with the wrapper view, but instead of calculating the height for the wrapper, I set the bottom wrapper view to match the bottom of the label with optional priority and set the wrapper height constraint to switch between a static value and the height of the inner label —which still heights the calculated height.

Comment: I'm not aware of that possibility. The easiest way is to test it out, which I guess you tried.