# when i change the priority of constraint then changes are not animating with UpdateconstraintIfNeeded

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, autolayout

i was doing one example in that i have taken 2 constarints like

topconstarints = 150 and priority is 999

and

top2constraint = 0 and priority is 998

and when i change the priority of

```
topconstarints.priority = 998
```

and

```
top2constraint.priority = 999
```

and i call updateConstraintsIfNeeded() then it not animating the changes but if the constraints having priority of 1000 and if i change that constraint then it is working so can any one explain me what is going on here

Comment: you need to call only layoutIfNeeded for the container view

Comment: ok but why it is not working with UpdateConstraintsIfNeeded but it is working with priority having 1000

Answer (score 2):

Few weeks ago there was a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48062369/2912282) here, I was playing around with it and it seems you cannot animate the view just by changing the priority of the constraints.

You have two options, if the difference between the constraints is only in their constant.

1. Have just a single one constraint, and simply change its constant.
2. Keep both constraints, but always have activated only a single one:

   ```
   topconstraint = ... // create a constraint 1
   topconstraint.isActive = true // activate it
   top2constraint = ... // also create it and keep it, but don't activate it
   ```

   And then later, when you want to animate the change:

   ```
   self.view.layoutIfNeeded() // just in case there are still some old changes to the autolayout

   topconstraint.isActive = false // deactivate the old one
   top2constraint.isActive = true // activate the new one
   self.view.setNeedsLayout() // tell the auto layout that changes have been made

   UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4) {
       // and then finally animate the changes
       self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
   }
   ```